# Read using CSV File Format in BigQuery

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Hi I am able to read Avro file in BigQuery using following code.

```
val fClass = classOf[AvroBigQueryInputFormat]
val kClass = classOf[LongWritable]
val vClass = classOf[GenericData.Record]
val rdd = sc
  .newAPIHadoopRDD(conf, fClass, kClass, vClass)
  .map(_._2)
```

My question is how to read CSV file similar to Avro. I didn't find any CSVFileFormat in "https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop/tree/master/bigquery/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/hadoop/io/bigquery".

Please suggest if you have any solution.